# Erroneous Matches with Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex, joomla, preg-match

```
$regexp = '/(?:<input\stype="hidden"\sname="){1}([a-zA-Z0-9]*)(?:"\svalue="1"\s\/>)/';
$response = '<input type="hidden" name="7d37dddd0eb2c85b8d394ef36b35f54f" value="1" />';
preg_match($regexp, $response, $matches);

echo $matches[1]; // Outputs: 7d37dddd0eb2c85b8d394ef36b35f54f
```

So I'm using this regular expression to search for an authentication token on a webpage implementing Joomla in order to preform a scripted login.

I've got all this working but am wondering what is wrong with my regular expression as it always returns 2 items.

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => 7d37dddd0eb2c85b8d394ef36b35f54f)
```

Also the name of the input I'm checking for changes every page load both in length and name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing is wrong. Item [0] always contains the entire match. From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) (emphasis mine):

> If `matches` is provided, then it is
>   filled with the results of search.
>   **`$matches[0]` will contain the text that
>   matched the full pattern**, `$matches[1]`
>   will have the text that matched the
>   first captured parenthesized
>   subpattern, and so on.

Your regex (overlooking the fact that you are working on HTML with regexes in the first place, which you know you shouldn't) is a bit too complicated.

```
$regexp = '#<input\s+type="hidden"\s+name="([0-9a-f]*)"\s+value="1"\s*/>#i'
```

- You don't need the non-capturing groups at all.
- You use `\s`, which limits you to a single character. `\s+` is probably better.
- Using something different than `/` as the regex boundary makes escaping of forward slashes in the regex unnecessary.
- Making the regex case-insensitive could be useful, too.
- The auth token looks like a hex string, so matching `a-z` is unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you. Your regex does seem easier to read and I know your not supposed to do html matching with regex, but this seemed like a great case for it.

Comment: @Ballsacian1: It's your funeral. ;-) Looking into DOMDocument::loadHTML and tackling this problem with DOM and XPath might be worthwhile nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

As per the manual entry for [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

> If matches is provided, then it is filled with the results of search. $matches[0] will contain the text that matched the full pattern, $matches[1] will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

Comment: And I guess the `[0] => [1]` is in fact (in the webpage source) `[0] => '<input type="hidden" name="7d37dddd0eb2c85b8d394ef36b35f54f" value="1" />' [1] =>`